# How were R2D2 and C3PO made in the original trilogy?

Tags: star-wars

I know they used a lot of mechanics back then, but were R2D2 and C3PO mechanical, a costume, or something else?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For c-3po, it was a costume, [Anthony Daniels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anthony_Daniels) played c-3po:

[image: Anthony Daniels as c3po]

For R2-D2, It was a costume and a remote controlled robot. CGI was also used in the prequel trilogy. So, they had [Kenny Baker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kenny_Baker) to play him :
[image: Kenny Baker inside R2-D2]

And from [Portrayal section of wookieepedia article on R2-D2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2#Portrayal) :

> Baker performed the role of R2-D2 inside a standing unit of the droid, wearing a specially-made suit and manipulating the droid's lights and appendages, turning his head, rocking his body back and forth, and moving his eye with a rod. **In addition to Baker's unit, every Star Wars film has made use of a number of remote control units, as Baker's was largely immobile.**
>   [...]
>   A computer-generated R2-D2 was also used in many scenes of the prequel trilogy, including a scene in Episode II where the character walks up a staircase. Baker has stated that he would never have been able to do that in his costume.

Comment: Cool but how were the costume made because it looks like c-3po wasn't a costume because of the wire's
And you have a fake picture of r2-d2

Comment: @Justin - that's not a fake. That is the actor that played R2-D2 in many scenes. If you follow the link provided, you'll see that Mr. Baker is a little person, who also played one of the Ewoks.