# How did Kenny Baker play R2-D2 in Star Wars?

Tags: character, star-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How were R2D2 and C3PO made in the original trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/how-were-r2d2-and-c3po-made-in-the-original-trilogy)

I found out that [R2-D2](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000054/) was played by [Kenny Baker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0048652/) and I am surprised. How did he control it? Did he really get inside it?

Comment: see [How were R2D2 and C3PO made in the original trilogy?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/how-were-r2d2-and-c3po-made-in-the-original-trilogy/1662#1662)

Comment: Hi. Whilst not an exact duplicate, everything this question asks is found in the duplicate found by DavRob60